# IdSrv4 - Access Token Validator EndPoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I set up an Identity Server 4 server. In identity server 3 we have the endpoint available, so we can do the following:

```
POST /connect/accesstokenvalidation

token=<token>
```

I supposed it is the same on identity server 4, but I get a `404 NOT FOUND`. Then I entered to: `http://my-endpoint.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` and the endpoint is not present.

Should I set up something to make it available on identity server 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [Introspection Endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/introspection.html?highlight=introspection).

```
POST /connect/introspect
Authorization: Basic xxxyyy

token=<token>
```

To autorize, use the HTTP Basic authorization flow: combine a `<scope>:<scope_secret>` pair and convert it into a Base64-encoded string (`xxxyyy` in example above). The `scope_secret` value can be specified in the ApiResource definition:

```
new ApiResource("myapi, "My API")
{
    Scopes = {new Scope("post-myapi")},
    ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("any_string_you_like".Sha256())},
}
```

Then, the POST request above should return the response similar to:

```
{
    "nbf": 1491850954,
    "exp": 1491854554,
    "iss": "api-auth",
    "aud": [
        "api-auth/resources",
        "myapi"
    ],
    "client_id": "foo",
    "scope": "post-myapi",
    "active": true
}
```

Full request (copied from Postman):

```
POST /connect/introspect HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:6000
Authorization: Basic YXBpLWlzc3VlczpzY29wZVNlY3JldA==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

token=.......
```

Comment: I tried using the introspect endpoint in postman and I receive `401 unauthorized`, but testing it on my api the token works. What would be the problem?

Comment: @FacundoGFlores have you registered a scope secret as described above? I successfully call this endpoint in Postman so I've added full request to answer.

Comment: thank you very much! Just one point  that was hard to notice for me is that when you call authorization I need to call `btoa(scopename:secret)` (I had to read the console logs). Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: @FacundoGFlores thank you too. I added clarification to answer. Also, you can easily set scopename and secret in Postman `Authorization` tab. It encodes the pair and adds a request header automatically.